# Merging content of 2 directories on separate git branches and integrating branches later

Tags: git

I have a project hosted at GitHub.  We are developing a new set of features on a shared topic branch named metamodel which pushed to GitHub.  At the same time we have ongoing bug-fix work happening on master.  The plan is to eventually integrate metamodel back into master at which point the metamodel branch would go away.  Both of these branches contain 2 directories whose contents we want to merge into 1 single directory.  At this point the 2 directories are already divergent between the 2 branches.  Furthermore, they will continue to diverge even more until the branch integration.

What will happen when I go to integrate the branches together if I have merged the 2 directories together on each branch independently?  We, as a project, have elected to integrate branches by means of rebasing in case that has bearing here.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't really care about directories, or even file names. It cares about content. And it is rather intelligent about merging (it'll figure out when things are simply moved or renamed).

So, basically, in answer to your question of "what will happen when we integrate these branches together", the answer is - "I don't know." I haven't seen the content. But I can tell you that Git will rather efficiently compare the differences/similarities in content, and combine together everything rather nicely. Anything that Git gets stuck on will just show up as a merge conflict, and you'll just have to resolve those on a case-by-case basis.

In this situation, I'd be careful with the rebasing, considering that your Git history and changes are starting to become rather complex. A rebase may work fine, but I'd be ready to rollback in case it gets messy.

Since your branches are strong diverged and gone different routes and paths, you may be better off doing a straight merge to bring them back together. That way you don't risk rewriting history in a detrimental/unrecoverable way (remember that rebasing is form of rewriting history). Plus, a straight Git merge will produce a new commit with everything combined, which (considering the drastic differences that have occurred), may be a valuable "fork-in-the-road" commit to have, just in case you need to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing is nice as it cleans up your history but I would definitely not do it in a complicated situation like thus.

Basically if you have ever pushed a branch to remote you'll want to avoid using rebase on that branch in most cases.  It's nice for a few local changes on a branch to improve the history, but after that, and a push to remote, just use merge.

I would just focus on merge and cleaning up any conflicts.